# How to convert the following properties from CSS to Mui?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate my css code to using the sx prop and styled() that MUI provides, but I didn't see in documentation how I can convert the following to the proper MUI syntax. Can anyone help me please?

```
.landing {
  position: relative;
  max-height: fit-content;
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  left: calc(50% - 800.05px / 2 - 204.98px);
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
}
```

In jsx:

```
<div className={homeStyles.landing}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MUI makeStyles to implement this.
The code example like below:

```js
const homeStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    landing: {
        position: 'relative',
        letterSpacing: '2px'
    }
})
```

And then you can use this class.

```js
const styles = homeStyles();

<div className={styles.landing}>hi</div>
```

Here is the documentation you can refer:
[makeStyles](https://mui.com/system/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook)

Comment: the documentation says @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. Is there a solution using @mui/system?

Comment: Yeah, you can using the @mui/system to implement it, so will using sx to setup your css code, example: <Grid sx={{position: 'relative', letterSpacing: '2px'}} >